# How to create a column with row number inf pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I need to create a column in pyspark with has the row number of each row. I'm s`monotonically_increasing_id` function, but it sometimes generate very large values. How can I generate a column which has the values starting from 1 and goes to size of my dataframe?

```
top_seller_elast_df = top_seller_elast_df.withColumn("rank", F.monotonically_increasing_id() + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`row_number()`** function by ordering to **`monotonically_increasing_id()`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
w=Window.orderBy("mid")

top_seller_elast_df = top_seller_elast_df.withColumn("mid", monotonically_increasing_id())
    
top_seller_elast_df.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(w)).show()
```